# What happens to alloc if initWithX fails?

Tags: objective-c, init, alloc

It is common practice to write `MyClass* obj = [[MyClass alloc] initWithX:X]` in Objective-C. `initWithX` is usually defined as

```
- (MyClass*) initWithX: (MyArgClass*) X {
    if (self = [super init])  {
        // initialize
    }
    return self;
}
```

My question is: what if initialize fails? I don't want to throw exceptions, but, how do I indicate error? If I return `nil`, the caller will not be able to release the pointer.

Comment: Please add a reason if you are downgrading. If I don't know what the error is how would I understand the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If initialization fails for any reason you should release self. For an exception that may occur in your initialization you need to add you `@try` `@catch` as appropriate so you can release `self`.

```
- (MyClass*) initWithX: (MyArgClass*) X {
    if (self = [super init])  {
        // initialize
        if(myInitializationCodeFailed)
        {
                [self release];
                return nil;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Update**

If it is possible for your initialization fail I would not raise an exception from with in your initialization code. If you would like to provide the caller with information I would refactor the initializer to accept an [`NSError`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html) to be returned.

```
- (MyClass*) initWithX: (MyArgClass*) X error:(NSError**)error {
```

As Alexei Sholik points in the comments check out the [Handling Initialization Failure](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13) section of Allocating and Initializing Objects.

Comment: I didn't know it is possible to release self!! Blame it on my C++ background :).

Comment: It is what Apple recommends to do. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW1 (see subsection 'Handling Initialization Failure')

Comment: +1 Good find on that article I was going off of personal experience.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW1) answers your question.

> #### Handling Initialization Failure
>
> In general, if there is a problem during an initialization method, you should call the `release` method on `self` and return `nil`.
>
> There are two main consequences of this policy:
>
> - Any object (whether your own class, a subclass, or an external caller) that receives `nil` from an initializer method should be able to deal with it. In the unlikely case that the caller has established any external references to the object before the call, you must undo any connections.
> - You must make sure that `dealloc` methods are safe in the presence of partially initialized objects.
>
> ...